# iText - Convert field names with square brackets to fields without square brackets?

Tags: itext, xfa

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class PDFFile {


 public static final String xfaForm3 = "C:/PDF_Service/pdf-project/src/sample.pdf";
 public static final String dest = "sample2.xml";

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

    PdfReader reader; 
    PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
    AcroFields form;

    try{

       reader = new PdfReader(xfaForm3);
       PdfStamper stamper2 = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
       form = stamper2.getAcroFields();
       stamper2.close();
       Set<String> fldNames = form.getFields().keySet();


      for (String fldName : fldNames) 

      {

        System.out.println( fldName +  " : " + form.getField( fldName ) );

       }


      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();

       }    
   }
```

}

My code above is reading a PDF file that has the XFA format and it prints out something that looks like this:

F[0].P1[0].FFField1[14] : 11 Pine Drive

Instead of printing out "F[0].P1[0].FFField1[14]", how can I print out "Address"?

I would like my code to print out this:

Address : 11 Pine Drive

Comment: That is only possible if the field dictionary have a `TU` entry. Do they have such an entry?

Comment: I do not have such as entry. How do I create a field dictionary and a TU entry?